# How to fetch all instances of Scriptable Objects implementing MyClass<T>?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Given this base class for Scriptable Objects in Unity

```
public abstract class MyBaseScriptableObject<T> : ScriptableObject { }
```

I can inherit from it

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Foo", menuName = "My files.../Bar")]
public sealed class Foo : MyBaseScriptableObject<string> { }
```

and create new Scriptable Objects of type `Foo` in the Editor.

I want to create a custom Editor window holding a list of all created "instances" inheriting from `MyBaseScriptableObject<T>`. I first tried to fetch all the instances of type `MyBaseScriptableObject<string>` in my custom editor window script

```
private void ListAllInstances()
{
    string[] guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:"+ typeof(MyBaseScriptableObject<string>).Name);

    Debug.Log($"Found: {guids.Length}");
}
```

I created one Scriptable Object of type `Foo`. Unfortunately the count is 0, so my code was not able to find any Scriptable Object.

Does someone know what's missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:Foo")` to find all Foo objects or you can find all MyBaseScriptableObject objects `AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:MyBaseScriptableObject")`. There is no way you can use generics as type filter string. You can also make use of folders, put different types in different folders and reduce search to those folders as needed.

Comment: Yep, the FindAssets API is quite broken, poorly maintained by Unity. The team responsible did a partial rewrite but didn't test half the scenarios and broke a lot in the process. This particular bug is fixable in the space of a few seconds by anyone working at Unity but they have refused to do it (despite multiple bug reports and lengthy debates) - if you're happy to do a lot of reflection calls you can try fixing it yourself, but the Unity staff don't want you to, so they've deliberately made the classes 'internal' despite no changes from them in 4+ years.